# How to get CSV content with csv-writer without writing to a file system

Tags: node.js

- Usually we need to write the csv file and then read it again to get the content of the ReadStream csv file.

This is my current code

```
const csvWriter = createObjectCsvWriter({
      path: csvfilepath + '.csv',
      header: [
        //Headerなしの場合
        'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5',
        'field6', 'field7', 'field8', 'field9', 'field10',
        'field11', 'field12', 'field13', 'field14', 'field15',
        'field16', 'field17', 'field18', 'field19', 'field20',
        'field21', 'field22', 'field23', 'field24', 'field25',
        'field26', 'field27', 'field28', 'field29', 'field30',
        'field31', 'field32', 'field33', 'field34', 'field35',
        'field36', 'field37', 'field38', 'field39', 'field40',
        'field41', 'field42', 'field43', 'field44'
      ],
      encoding: 'utf8',
      append: false, // append : no header if true
    });
    await csvWriter.writeRecords(records);  
    inputFile = fs.createReadStream(csvfilepath + '.csv');
```

- How can I get csv file contents from array without writing file?

Answer (score 0):

A workflow to handle such cases:

- debug your application and inspect how your object of interest looks:
  [image: List item]
- here we see some `FileWriter` instance, go to `node_modules` and check its source:

```
import {promisify} from './lang/promise';
import {writeFile} from 'fs';

const writeFilePromise = promisify(writeFile);

const DEFAULT_ENCODING = 'utf8';

export class FileWriter {

   constructor(private readonly path: string,
               private append: boolean,
               private readonly encoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING) {
   }

   async write(string: string): Promise<void> {
       await writeFilePromise(this.path, string, this.getWriteOption());
       this.append = true;
   }

   private getWriteOption() {
       return {
           encoding: this.encoding,
           flag: this.append ? 'a' : 'w'
       };
   }
}
```

- It's obvious we need to monkey patch the `write` method, so the solution:

```
import { createObjectCsvWriter } from 'csv-writer'

const csvWriter = createObjectCsvWriter({
    path: 'dummy.csv',
    header: [
        'field1', 'field2'
    ],
    encoding: 'utf8',
    append: false, // append : no header if true
});

const records = [{ field1: 'val1', field2: 'val2' }];

let csv = '';
csvWriter.fileWriter.write = str => csv += str;

await csvWriter.writeRecords(records);

console.log(csv);
```

the output:

```
val1,val2
```